# Does Chef include comments in line count

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I'm looking at output in chef-stacktrace.out to troubleshoot a cookbook error.

The output indicates an error corresponding to an earlier line than I see in my code. The only reason that would make sense is a difference in line counts due to comments before said code.

As a rule, would I expect Chef to ignore comments when referring to a line in a cookbook/etc?

Cookbook not shown due to sensitive information.

Comment: clarify your question

Comment: No. Chef shows the exact line number, without stripping out comments. The difference in line number may arise due to some modifications in your local file, that are not in production server yet.

Comment: Perfect  - thanks Draco